# SQL Nested select grouped with several rows of results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hope this makes sense..

I have the following database tabels.
[image]

I am trying to group a resultset together in an SQL statement.

This is my current SQL statements:

```
SELECT 
    Patient.ID,
    Patient.Name,
    AnimalType.Value as AnimalType,
    Patient.Age,
    Customer.Firstname,
    Customer.Lastname

FROM Patient
    INNER JOIN Customer ON Patient.Owner_FK = Customer.ID
    INNER JOIN AnimalType ON Patient.Type_FK = AnimalType.ID

SELECT 
    Treatment.Treatment_Date,
    TreatmentType.Type
FROM Treatment
    INNER JOIN TreatmentItem ON Treatment.ID = TreatmentItem.Treatment_FK
    INNER JOIN TreatmentType ON TreatmentItem.TreatmentType_FK = TreatmentType.ID
    INNER JOIN Patient ON TreatmentItem.Patient_FK = Patient.ID
WHERE Patient.ID = 132
```

There are two issues with this, 
I have a static ID, and the results are split.

This is result of the above SQL's
[image]
[image]
My Issue is that the last resultset, should be together with the corresponding "Animal (patient)".

But without duplicate data. I could get the data all in one go, but then i would have a lot of duplicate rows of data with only the TreatmentType being different..

So how do i make this work ? 
I have searched to no avail, and have not been able to make a correct Group by, that would make it work.

Does it make any sense ?
Is it even possible ?

example of desired result:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of the result you want to get? My understanding is that you want to list all the treatments received by an animal in a single result row.

Comment: It's possible, and it's been asked and answered before.   Exactly which question you are duplicating depends on the way you want the results to look, which you haven't provided.

Comment: @Sirmyself added an example of the result i would like to achive.

Comment: @Sirmyself sorry, but i had to create an example... sorry i took a couple of minutes for it...

Comment: @andrelange91 it's ok, I removed my downvote

Comment: @TabAlleman i have not been able to find a specific solution which could help me.

Comment: I found a lot of duplicates with this google search:   `sql server replace duplicate values with blank`.   I'll pick one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate data in unique rows, show blank instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574119/duplicate-data-in-unique-rows-show-blank-instead)

Comment: maybe take a look at this page : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a66736/ch42.htm it's quite comprehensive

Comment: I will take a lot, thank you @Sirmyself

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve what you want with a single query, [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) statements, and the  [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) function, but it would require conversions of all non-text columns.

Here is a rough stab at a potential solution (I did not build your DB, so I haven't verified that this exact SQL runs, but the overall concept works).

```
WITH    CTE_PatientTreatments AS (
    SELECT 
        -- Get the row number for each treatment for a given patient
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Patient.ID ORDER BY Treatment.ID) AS RowNum,
        Patient.ID,
        Patient.Name,
        AnimalType.Value as AnimalType,
        Patient.Age,
        Customer.Firstname,
        Customer.Lastname,
        Treatment.Treatment_Date,
        TreatmentType.Type
    FROM Patient
        INNER JOIN Customer ON Patient.Owner_FK = Customer.ID
        INNER JOIN AnimalType ON Patient.Type_FK = AnimalType.ID
        INNER JOIN TreatmentItem ON TreatmentItem.Patient_FK = Patient.ID
        INNER JOIN Treatment ON Treatment.ID = TreatmentItem.Treatment_FK
        INNER JOIN TreatmentType ON TreatmentItem.TreatmentType_FK = TreatmentType.ID
    WHERE Patient.ID = 132
    -- Ensure rows are sorted so that rows for the same patient are always together
    ORDER BY Patient.ID, Treatment.ID
)
-- Only display patient information for the first row
SELECT  -- Convert numeric columns to text so that the "ELSE ''" doesn't get coerced into a number (0)
        CASE WHEN (RowNum > 1) THEN '' ELSE CAST(ID AS VARCHAR) END AS ID,
        CASE WHEN (RowNum > 1) THEN '' ELSE Name END AS Name,
        CASE WHEN (RowNum > 1) THEN '' ELSE AnimalType END AS AnimalType,
        CASE WHEN (RowNum > 1) THEN '' ELSE CAST(Age AS VARCHAR) END AS Age,
        CASE WHEN (RowNum > 1) THEN '' ELSE Firstname END AS Firstname,
        CASE WHEN (RowNum > 1) THEN '' ELSE Lastname END AS Lastname,
        Treatment_Date,
        Type
FROM    CTE_PatientTreatments
```